# Xamarin crashing on build with Compiler crashed code 1

Tags: xamarin

I have installed Xamarin and am trying to build my first solution.

So far I have created the new solution, then tried to build and run it. It's blank so I would expect it to at least compile.

Unfortunately I'm getting the error 'Compiler crashed code 1'.

So far I have reinstalled the Mono Framework and changed the MCS file to reference versions/current as found [here](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/30097/task-csc-execution-failed-xs-on-mac-os-x-yosemite).

The full error is:

```
Project "/Users/bwashbourn/Projects/Who'sKeen/Who'sKeen.csproj" (Build target(s)):

Target PrepareForBuild:
    Configuration: Debug Platform: AnyCPU

Target GenerateSatelliteAssemblies:
No input files were specified for target GenerateSatelliteAssemblies, skipping.

Target _CoreXamlG:
No input files were specified for target _CoreXamlG, skipping.

Target GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because its outputs are up-to-date.

Target CoreCompile:
    Tool /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.0/lib/mono/4.5/mcs.exe execution started with arguments: /noconfig /debug:full /debug+ /optimize- /out:"obj/Debug/Who'sKeen.dll" Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs "Who'sKeen.cs" /target:library /define:DEBUG /nostdlib /reference:packages/Xamarin.Forms.1.3.3.6323/lib/portable-win+net45+wp80+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10+Xamarin.iOS10/Xamarin.Forms.Core.dll /reference:packages/Xamarin.Forms.1.3.3.6323/lib/portable-win+net45+wp80+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10+Xamarin.iOS10/Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.0/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile78/Microsoft.CSharp.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.0/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile78/System.Collections.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.0/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile78/System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.0/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile78/System.ComponentModel.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.0/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile78/System.Core.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.0/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile78/System.Diagnostics.Contracts.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.0/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile78/System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.0/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile78/System.Diagnostics.Tools.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.0/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile78/System.Dynamic.Runtime.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.0/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile78/System.Globalization.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.0/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile78/System.IO.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.0/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile78/System.Linq.Expressions.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.0/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile78/System.Linq.Queryable.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.0/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile78/System.Linq.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.0/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile78/System.Net.NetworkInformation.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.0/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile78/System.Net.Primitives.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.0/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile78/System.Net.Requests.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.0/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile78/System.Net.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.0/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile78/System.ObjectModel.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.0/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile78/System.Reflection.Extensions.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.0/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile78/System.Reflection.Primitives.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.0/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile78/System.Reflection.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.0/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile78/System.Resources.ResourceManager.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.0/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile78/System.Runtime.Extensions.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.0/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile78/System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.0/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile78/System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.0/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile78/System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.0/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile78/System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.0/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile78/System.Runtime.Serialization.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.0/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile78/System.Runtime.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.0/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile78/System.Security.Principal.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.0/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile78/System.ServiceModel.Http.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.0/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile78/System.ServiceModel.Primitives.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.0/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile78/System.ServiceModel.Security.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.0/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile78/System.ServiceModel.Web.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.0/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile78/System.ServiceModel.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.0/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile78/System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.0/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile78/System.Text.Encoding.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.0/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile78/System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.0/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile78/System.Threading.Tasks.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.0/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile78/System.Threading.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.0/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile78/System.Windows.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.0/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile78/System.Xml.Linq.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.0/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile78/System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.0/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile78/System.Xml.Serialization.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.0/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile78/System.Xml.XDocument.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.0/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile78/System.Xml.XmlSerializer.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.0/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile78/System.Xml.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.0/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile78/System.dll /reference:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.0/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETPortable/v4.5/Profile/Profile78/mscorlib.dll /warn:4

    Unhandled Exception:
    System.IO.FileLoadException: I/O Error
      at IKVM.Reflection.AssemblyName..ctor (System.String assemblyName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at Mono.CSharp.AssemblyDefinition.CreateAssemblyName () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at Mono.CSharp.AssemblyDefinitionStatic.Create (IKVM.Reflection.Universe domain) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at Mono.CSharp.Driver.Compile () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at Mono.CSharp.Driver.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
    [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.IO.FileLoadException: I/O Error
      at IKVM.Reflection.AssemblyName..ctor (System.String assemblyName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at Mono.CSharp.AssemblyDefinition.CreateAssemblyName () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at Mono.CSharp.AssemblyDefinitionStatic.Create (IKVM.Reflection.Universe domain) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at Mono.CSharp.Driver.Compile () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at Mono.CSharp.Driver.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.0/lib/mono/4.5/Microsoft.CSharp.targets: error : Compiler crashed with code: 1.
Task "Csc" execution -- FAILED
Done building target "CoreCompile" in project "/Users/bwashbourn/Projects/Who'sKeen/Who'sKeen.csproj".-- FAILED

Done building project "/Users/bwashbourn/Projects/Who'sKeen/Who'sKeen.csproj".-- FAILED

Build FAILED.
Errors:

/Users/bwashbourn/Projects/Who'sKeen/Who'sKeen.csproj (Build) ->
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.0/lib/mono/4.5/Microsoft.CSharp.targets (CoreCompile target) ->

/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.0/lib/mono/4.5/Microsoft.CSharp.targets: error : Compiler crashed with code: 1.

 0 Warning(s)
 1 Error(s)`
```

Answer (score 1):

> /Users/bwashbourn/Projects/Who'sKeen/Who'sKeen.csproj

Without looking into this too much, the apostrophe in the project name is probably causing an issue, can you try a project and folder without that in the name?